# Group Box content - hide based on cell value

Tags: vba

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case Range("B14")

    Case "Medium Risk"
        Rows("6:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case Else
        Rows("6:12").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

What I need is: to hide Group Box "content" based on the value in B14. 
Group Box 15 surrounds a CheckBox8_Click.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that I will simply settle with hiding a row [based on cell criteria] where the object is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case Range("B14")

    Case "Medium Risk"
        Rows("6:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Else
        Rows("6:12").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("24").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```